# To Encapsulate or Not To Encapsulate

Tags: oop, swift, encapsulation

I have a nice MVC setup going with my latest project which will soon scale up to needing more people working on the code I have created. My project is in Swift.

As such I am curious from people who have worked on larger scale projects what the cleanest approach is to encapsulating objects in the given scenario.

1. I have a custom image class: MyImage
2. I have special objects which holds a MyImage object, and various other bits of data. Lets call it DataObject.

My question is regarding to nesting. Is it better to have DataObject encapsulate all the MyImage functions with its own functions.

```
DataObject.doSomething()
```

Or is it better practice (esp when working with others) to leave all those MyImage functions on the MyImage object and just make the MyImage object accessible from the DataObject:

```
DataObject.myImage.doSomething()
```

Comment: Hi again. :) I would ask first why you have a custom image class. You have actually subclassed UIImage? That is a very odd thing to do. Why have you done that?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing Matt mentioned. It might be useful to see some code to have a better idea of the context.

Comment: I didn't subclass UIImage, I made a super class with it. So Its a UIView with a UIScrollView, UImageView and a bunch of other things (like gestures) which lets me do a lot of fun things easily. Like zooming, panning, rotating etc etc

Comment: Then you're not providing enough info for anyone to give a meaningful answer. You want advice about your architecture but you are not _revealing_ your architecture. Voting to close on that basis.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want people to use your software. Do they need knowledge of `MyImage`? If not, all of `MyImage`'s functions should be encapsulated within `DataObject` so they have no knowledge of what `DataObject` is doing to it. Making `MyImage` accessible is breaking encapsulation in my opinion because it is giving the user too much visibility into what is happening behind the scenes of `DataObject`.

Comment: But then my thought is this. We will eventually need say, DataObject2, DataObject3 etc which are all different. Some may or may not have a MyImage, so I feel like I would be doing a lot of redundant work by constantly writing wrapper functions wouldn't I?

Comment: So then why not have MyImage be a separate entity entirely managed by the user, and then have a DataObject.setMyImage(MyImage) function?